# MAGENTO : HOW TO IMPROVE FIRST BYTE TIME

Tags: performance, caching, magento-1.7, apc

after deleting the cache of my browser. my magento website is loaded very slowly.
but when once it open it loaded fastly.
obviously its because of cache.
But my Question is to open my website on first link.
as I m using apache server.

Comment: on first hit my website should load faster.

Comment: is anyone can help me to solve this question..?

Comment: should I remove this question.....?

Comment: The same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404086/how-to-reduce-ttfb-time-to-first-byte-of-my-magento-application/37977544#37977544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the number of http requests. By using merging JS/CSS and use CDN for images